# Overlapping local and LDAP usernames

Tags: rhel, users, authentication, ldap

We have several RHEL 6/7/8 machines where user authentication is done through LDAP.

One of our sysadmins would like to set up local accounts for some users on some machines, with the local username the same as the LDAP username, and have the local account take precedence. The purpose is to specify a different login shell for these users on these machines.

I think it's a bad idea as it complicates the lives both of the sysadmin and the user (think about the user changing their password and not knowing whether the change is local or spread, through LDAP, to all servers).

However, can it be done?

[This answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/529978/164103) about a similar problem proposes a workaround which looks very ugly to me:

> Workaround 2: A little more complicated but comes down to adding the local user with the same uidNumber as in LDAP.
>
> 1. Lookup LDAP uidNumber with getent, ldapsearch, or smbldap-usershow
> 2. Temporarily disable the user in LDAP in order to add the local user without conflicts
> 3. Create the local account matching the uidNumber with LDAP
> 4. Re-enable the user in LDAP

Comment: It depends on your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` - whatever matches there first wins. By keeping `file` ahead of `ldap` or `sss`, I have kept local accounts that override LDAP

Comment: That's the point: `/etc/nsswitch.conf` specifies `files sss` but adding a local user with same username as a LDAP user results in an error "user already exists".

Comment: What do you use to add the user? I just copy the output of `getent passwd` (or group or shadow as appropriate) using `vipw` with manual edits

Comment: The good ol' `adduser`

Comment: `adduser` is a wrapper script that varies in functionality between various distributions, but with plenty of safeguards in any case. I'd say this is an exceptional case where consciously overriding it is warranted. Use `useradd` or similar if `vipw` is not to your taste.

Comment: LDAP overlays might be useful. I'll be testing those next week for a similar purpose, but I hope someone else here gets to it before then.

Comment: Have a look at `sssd.conf` and the `filter_users` option.  This may be usable to hide the LDAP user from the machine, so only the local user is found

Comment: If it's just about the login shell, adn you're already using sssd, doesn't take `sss_override` take precedence over the value in LDAP anyway?